# how to manage a timer in a pytest?

Tags: ros2, python, ros-humble, timer, unit-testing

I've got a Node that publish a message in a timer. The code works fine but I want to write a pytest to ensure the message is published.

My test code is this one

```
class TestMyNode:
    def test_publish(self, my_node):
        # my_node is a fixture, the node object
        # the publish call is done in a timer in the __init__
        
        # I subsribe to the topic where the message is published
        my_node.create_subscription(
            String, TOPIC,
            self.cb,
            QOS_PROFILE,
        )

        # action
        rclpy.spin_once(my_node, timeout_sec=5.0)
        assert self.var.data == "expected"

    def cb(self, msg):
        print(f"cb - reçu : {msg}")
        self.var = msg
```

The **init** code that I want to test is like

```
def __init__(self):
    self.__action_publisher = self.create_publisher(String, TOPIC, QOS_PROFILE, callback_group=ReentrantCallbackGroup())
    
    # if called directly, the pytest is ok
    # self.__publish_msg()

    # with the timer, the callback is never called
    timer_period = 0.2
    self.__timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.__publish_msg)
```

I don't understand how I should write this test.